# Tag Suggestions

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

I think it would be nice to have more (and more specific) tags for a/v effects:

- video-effects
- audio-effects
- digital-effects

... and some tags about filming:

- camera-rigs
- camera-angles

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding specific tags isn't really a "feature suggestion." Tags get created by the authors when those questions get asked.

So, if you'd like to see more questions on the subjects you outlined above, ask them.

If those questions have already been asked but not properly tagged, you can either add those tags yourself (if you have +500 rep) or [suggest those tags be added](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/).

Comment: I dont have enough rep to create tags when I ask questions but I will request edits with them.